# Sed command to replace a string in a file not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, gnu

While trying to execute below sed command from my VM

```
sudo -S shv6 <IP> "sed -i 's#<RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem>INFO</RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem>#<RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem>DEBUG</RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem><XREPluginGraphicsItem>DEBUG</XREPluginGraphicsItem>#g' /op/log.xml"
```

I observed following error message

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: -c: line 0: `sed -i s#<RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem>INFO</RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem>#<RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem>DEBUG</RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem><XREPluginGraphicsItem>DEBUG</XREPluginGraphicsItem>#g /op/log.xml'
```

Whats wrong with my sed command.

Comment: It is the shell complaining; your single quotes are missing in action by the time it is complaining.  With all those XML/HTML angle brackets, the shell might be having a field day redirecting and re-redirecting, and re-re-re-redirecting.  Or it may be long past time I was abed and asleep.  Is the target machine using GNU `sed`; if not, the `-i` option may give trouble.

Comment: Please try a simplified command. I see `<IP>` in your command, is this the real code? It would try to read input from the file IP and write everything to a multiline command starting with `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the below command worked.

```
sudo -S shv6 <IP> "sed -i 's#\\<RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem\\>LOG\\<\\/RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem\\>#\\<RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem\\>DEBUG\\<\\/RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem\\>\\<RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem\\>DEBUG\\<\\/RDKBrowserHtmlViewItem\\>#g' /op/log.xml"
```

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.  It looks like there were enough shell-like operations stripping quotes that it was the problem after all.